# Oracle - Calling Stored Procedure in a Loop in another Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I reviewed the answers to similar inquiries but continue to get another error that cannot seem to resolved by adding in the schema the proc was created under.

This is the code I am attempting to run:

```
create or replace procedure prcReturnDVD
-- define the parameters that this proc will accept
(memberid_in integer, dvd_in integer)
 is
 -- Define local variables
  vNumRem number(2);
BEGIN
-- Update the rental table with the current date
  update rental set rentalreturneddate = current_date where memberid = memberid_in and dvdid = dvd_in;
-- update DVD quantityonhand to reflect the return
  update dvd set dvdquantityonhand = dvdquantityonhand + 1 where dvdid = dvd_in;
-- Check to see how many DVDs are available for rent for this member
  select get_rentalsremaining(memberid_in) into vNumRem from dual;
-- Evaluate the next action depending on number of remaining DVD rentals available
  if vNumRem >= 1 then
  -- need to write a for loop in order to cycle through the DVDs that need to be shipped out
    while vNumRem >= 0 
    loop
      SYSTEM.prcShipNextDVD(memberid_in);
      vNumRem := vNumRem - 1;
    end loop;
  elsif vNumRem = 0 then
  -- message that no rentals are allowed
    dbms_output.put_line('No more rentals allowed.');
  end if;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('No Data Returned, process failed.');
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Too many rows returned into variable, check data and try again.');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('An unidentified error has occured. Please research issue with procedure.');
END;
/
```

Inside the LOOP statement I am attempting to call another procedure written previous by the same user (I'm using SYSTEM only because it's only a homework assignment and it simplifies permissions):

```
create or replace procedure prcShipNextDVD
-- define the parameters that this proc will accept
(memberid_in integer)
 is
 -- Define local variables
  vCountOut number(2);
  vAllowedOut number(2);
  vNextDvd number(16);
  vAddedInQueue date;
  vPlaceInQueue number(5);
BEGIN
-- ensure the member is eligible to take out another DVD at this time
-- See how many movies the member currently has out
  select count(*) into vCountOut from rental where memberid = memberid_in and rentalreturneddate is null;
-- See how many movies the member is allowed to have out
  select membershiplimitpermonth into vAllowedOut from membership m, member p where m.membershipid = p.membershipid and p.memberid = memberid_in;
  IF vCountOut < vAllowedOut then
    -- If the number out currently is less than the number allowed out currently
    -- Get next DVD in queue available for shipment
    select get_nextdvd(memberid_in) into vNextDVD, datedaddedinqueue into vAddedInQueue, rentalpriority into vPlaceInQueue from rentalqueue where memberid = memberid_in;
    -- create new record in rental table for this shipment
    insert into rental (rentalid, memberid, dvdid, rentalrequestdate, rentalshippeddate) values (rental_seq.nextval, memberid_in, vNextDVD, vAddedInQueue, current_date);
    -- decrement dvdquantityon hand in dvd table
    update dvd set quantityonhand = quantityonhand - 1 where dvdid = vNextDVD;
    -- remove dvd from queue 
    delete from rentalqueue where memberid = memberid_in and dvdid = vNextDVD ;
    -- manage remaining rentalpriority records by decrementing them properly (like in 2.1)
    update rentalqueue set rentalpriority = rentalpriority - 1 where memberid = memberid_in and rentalpriority >= vPlaceInQueue;
  ELSE
    -- If the member already has the maximum number of movies out at this time
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'Maximum number of movies out reached. You are not allowed to check out another movie at this time.');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('No Data Returned, process failed.');
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Too many rows returned into variable, check data and try again.');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('An unidentified error has occured. Please research issue with procedure.');
END;
/
```

I am getting the following error even after adding the schema name to the procedure call. I've also tried running it with "execute" and "call" but know those do not work properly.

```
PROCEDURE PRCRETURNDVD compiled 
Errors: check compiler log 
19/7  PL/SQL: Statement ignored 
19/14 PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.PRCSHIPNEXTDVD is invalid
```

Any other recommendations on what I'm doing wrong on this one?

There is an issue with the procedure I'm calling but it does compile.

Comment: Oracle allows the same procedure to be compiled with different parameter lists. So you can store several "versions" of the same procedure. This is called overloading. For example, you could have myadd( n1 pls_integer, n2 pls_integer ) and myadd (n1 pls_integer, n2 pls_integer, n3 pls_integer ) and Oracle will keep both versions of the procedure. Make sure the procedure you have compiled without errors has the same parameter types as the one you're trying to call. For troubleshooting, I would just try and call one stored proc from SQL command line, not from the other proc.

Comment: I had the one I'm calling working earlier but now... it appears I have broken it :-/

Comment: Right.. on second thoughts, it's probably not related to having several versions floating around. Since I don't think you can do overloading except inside a package. After you compile, there's a command "show errors" to list any errors encountered. Does the compile of prcshipnextdvd come back clean, and then "show errors" is clean too?

Comment: Hit return too fast... Any ideas as to why this would be causing me the error immediately following it?

`select count(dvdid) into vCountOut from rental where memberid = memberid_in and rentalreturneddate is null;`
    
The error is pointing to where I am doing the count and placing it into one of my local variables. I've tried count(*) & count(dvdid) to see if it was an issue with an ambiguous reference. These both still produce the following errors:

`20/5           PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored`
`20/70          PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: Those figures 20/5 and 20/70 in your error message are the line number and position on the line that doesn't compile. Line 20 is the get_nextdvd line. It uses "into" several times, which is probably what's causing an error on that line.

Comment: I should have noted that those code pieces come from different procs. I think, based on something you said earlier, my issue is within the proc I'm calling, which is what I printed in the last comment. The error messages in my last comment correspond to the select statement in my last comment as well. Sorry to confuse things. I think I'm just thoroughly confused at this point.

Comment: That's fine, I think I understood how to move ahead in your example now that I saw the actual error it gives.. your error is on line 20 in prcshipnextdvd.. once you fix that error with multiple into statements, compile it again and fix errors until it's clean. Selects should be `select 1, 2, 3 into var1, var2, var3`. Writing `select 1 into var1, 2 into var2, 3 into var3` is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(as outlined in comments)

Fix the compile errors in prcShipNextDVD.

Then the call from the other stored procedure will work.

Comment: Went through and parsed apart the prcShipNextDVD code and found exactly the part that was causing the issue (about 2 statement down from where the errors were telling me it was). Once that was fixed, compiled without issue (after a few other column names were identified as misspelled and corrected) and then the subsequent proc with the call to the prcShipNextDVD compiled without complaint.

Thank you for your patience.